# Why does my HTML5 aside section not display in my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I added the following into my _SiteLayout.cshtml, just above the  section:

```
<aside class="amazad">
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        amazon_ad_tag = "platypus-42"; amazon_ad_width = "120"; amazon_ad_height = "600"; amazon_ad_link_target = "new";
    //--></script>
</aside>
```

and added this to Site.css:

```
.amazad {
    float: right;
}
```

But the ad strip doesn't display. Why not?

Everything inside the "aside" was generated by amazon's tools. They simply say to "place it in your html"; so what am I missing?

### UPDATE

This might be the issue (from amazon, via a Bing search):

*Relevant ads should appear on your pages shortly after you add the code, but sometimes it can take up to 48 hours for ads to show. This is because our crawler has to visit your page and determine its content so we can serve targeted ads.*

But I would think it would at least show a placeholder to indicate its eventual whereabouts...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags are run not displayed but run.

You are only declaring variables in your script tag. There is no code there about where the advertisements are loaded. Perhaps you are specifying the destination element in amazon_ad_tag property in which case it should be:

```
amazon_ad_tag = ".amazad"
```

Since that is the class for your aside